# SOQL on LeadHistory object

Tags: soql, leads

Need a SOQL query on LeadHistory object to track the date when the Lead owner was changed .Have already enabled Lead History tracking.

Scenario : Suppose there are two lead owners named Lead1 and Lead2 . At present(eg 4th- Mar-2014) Lead1 is the owner. And on 8th- Mar-2014, owner is changed to Lead2.

I need a SOQL to track the Lead Owner between these old date and new date.

Comment: So, what exactly are you having a problem with/question about ?

Comment: need a SOQL to get the date but I see that there is nothing like old date and new date in workbench.How do I get a query for this.?

Comment: you mean the date when the owner changed ? thats a single moment. I've answered based on that interpretation. If that's not what you're asking please update your question with a better/more detailed description of your scenario.

Answer (score 2):

As soon as field history tracking is enabled, the objectHistory table becomes accessible to soql, as you already indicate in your question.

```
SELECT CreatedById,CreatedDate,Field,Id,LeadId,NewValue, oldvalue 
FROM LeadHistory 
WHERE field = 'Owner'
```

This should give you 2 records per field change for this type, one with the text values and one with the salesforce ID values of the owner lookup. **The createdDate of the history record is the datetime the ownership on the lead record changed.**