# SOQL to get latest updates

Tags: soql

I'm not finding a way to get the latest updates
Scenario :

There are three people which is assigned to a given lead.

Lead name :  L1

User Name is John,Adam,Charles

```
Created Date    NewValue    OldValue    Lead
01/03/2014  Adam    John    L1
03/03/2014  Charles Adam    L1
07/03/2014  John    Charles L1
```

How do we fire a soql on L1's leadhistory
object so that we get only below result

```
07/03/2014  John    Charles
```

Please help

Comment: possible duplicate of [SOQL on LeadHistory object](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/29221/soql-on-leadhistory-object)

Comment: Thanks Samuel. This is different scenario now As that didn't fulfill the case and still stuck.

Comment: It looked like a different version of the same question to me. apologies. I have re-tracted my close vote.

Comment: Yes its the same version but this scenario is more specific and wanted to say the same thing in previous one. May be you have taken it in different way. Please suggest the efficient way to get a query. Thanks

Comment: The example in this question did help, see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a combination of `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` on your SOQL query to get that result.

Not much different than your other [question on how to query lead history](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/29221/soql-on-leadhistory-object)

```
SELECT CreatedById,CreatedDate,Field,Id,LeadId,NewValue, oldvalue 
FROM LeadHistory 
WHERE field = 'Owner' AND LieadId ='XXXXXXXXXX'
ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Thanks Samuel. But here I don't want to use LIMIIT.Is there any other way to get the same result ?

Comment: Can you explain why you do not want to use limit ? (Because you want to query for a bulk amount of leads at the same time ?)

Comment: Thanks again Samuel .I did the same query with the LIMIT. But i'm looking for a more efficient query. Is there any other way of getting same result . Help again will be appreciated.

Comment: You have to define what you consider "efficient" and what your application context and scenario is. It is very hard to give you the answer to your true question, only knowing half the question.

Comment: It does give me the latest one. Working on 4 leads only and want to know if there is other way like using aggregate functions like MAX or MIN ?

Answer (score 0):

This query should get only the latest one:

```
SELECT CreatedById,CreatedDate,Field,Id,LeadId,NewValue, oldvalue 
    FROM LeadHistory 
    WHERE field = 'Owner' AND  LeadID='yourleadid' ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC LIMIT 1
```